# What is the best way to cover your camera and microphone?

Tags: macbook-pro

*My question is not about "should I do it or not?"*

Is there any solutions to cover camera and microphone? Some people use tapes.

It will be interesting to have something that will not damage this parts and that could easy be "uninstalled" :)

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/67013/macbook-pro-camera-and-microphone-used-by-malware?rq=1

Comment: @Tetsujin the link you gave to me its more about the question "should I do it or not". I have read it - thank you.

Comment: The question is, [which is why I didn't flag it as a dupe] but the answers cover your exact requirements. Your question actually shows a lack of understanding of the issue - tape for the camera, sure, but covering a mic will not prevent it working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For the camera:**

You could try a small, completely opaque vinyl decal (or just a piece of one cut to the appropriate size, like those window decorations some people use that cling to glass without leaving a residue). I believe most of them adhere using a combination of static cling and a tacky (but not sticky) surface.

**For the microphone:**

As for the microphone, I don't know of anything that adheres to the brushed aluminum surface of a Mac that doesn't act like a sticker or tape, which may leave a residue behind. Magnets are a bad idea because they can damage internal components over time, like the speakers. Simply covering the microphone isn't a good option though because of how/where Apple installs the microphones in Macs. Sounds can still get through, although it would be muffled.

Instead, it's been suggested that buying a TRRS 'dummy jack' and inserting it into the headphone port is more effective because it mutes the built-in microphone until you unplug it. I personally haven't been able to locate these 'dummy jacks' that people speak of, but instead a headphone splitter with Mic support should do the trick and doesn't have to be too costly.

If you can't find a TRRS 'dummy jack' (one that has the mic support) or a headphone/microphone splitter you could try purchasing a pair of cheap headphones that have a built-in Mic (maybe even from the dollar store?) and cut off the cord, leaving just the little end that plugs into the headphone port. **Note**: I have not tried the cut-off headphones trick myself, so I can't guarantee that it will work with Macs.

*You also need to remember that if you do use one of these methods that while the Mac's audio jack/port is occupied your internal speakers will not function, as they've been switched off. This means that to listen to music or watch videos using the internal speakers you will need to remove the splitter or dummy jack.*

The headphone splitters with microphone support look like this:
[image]
[image]

You'll notice that the little end has 3 rings on it - not only two - the 3rd being for microphone support.

Comment: Great idea about the mic, although I believe that a hacker good enough can force the hardware (via firmware change in best case) to ignore the plug and use built-in mic.

Comment: A regular headphone plug won't work: it needs to have [four conductors (segments)](https://www.google.com/search?q=trrs+1/8%22+plug&tbm=isch) to engage the microphone circuit.

Comment: @Agent_L You can change a setting to specify if to use the built-in mic or the dummy mic.

Comment: @haykam If somebody has enough access to your machine to use it's mic to spy on you, a software setting is not of any value.

Comment: @NYkg "buy a cheap pair of headphones from the dollar store and cut off the cord, leaving just the little end that plugs into the headphone port" not really clear how should it work. After cutting off the cord - I have only little cord part. Let say 5 mm. And this small part should be plugged into 2 microphone slots (holes)?

Comment: Exactly. Cut it off and plug the things in.

Comment: @haykam can I damage this way the microphone itself?

Comment: Edited my post to be more specific - my apologies for the lack of detail the first time around! @JoshCaswell Thank you for reminding me to include this crucial piece of info.

Comment: @Agent_L Yes, a hacker that is good enough can always find a way in. But for the purpose of this original poster's question, let's assume he isn't being targeted specifically and wants ideas just for general peace of mind.

Comment: With the dummy jack for the microphone, the switching is most likely controlled by software. So even if you plug something into the jack you can still pull audio from the microphone with a click in any software program. I can do it on my machine with a dummy jack. So it is not going to protect from any type of surveillance

Comment: @user1886419 There is a physical hardware switch in the audio out port actually. It can actually get 'stuck on' when unplugging things sometimes and then your internal speakers still register with the system as 'unavailable' until it gets fixed. Sometimes plugging in/unplugging a pair of headphones repeatedly can solve the issue, if not you're usually left having to go to an Apple Store where in extreme cases they have to replace the logic board.

Comment: @NYKg but why can I plug headphones in and still use the built in mic? There is not a hardware switch for muting the built in microphone. It is hard wired and can be turned on at anytime regardless of what is plugged into where.

Answer (score 1):

For the camera, a sticky note works perfectly as it does not leave any residue.  As far as the microphone goes, @NYKg's solution will work quite well if you don't mind something hanging out of your headphone jack.

Answer (score 0):

the best hack I've found- a magnate for the camera. It does no sticky damage

Answer (score -2):

For the microphone: perhaps a small magnet?

Edit: the best I can get my laptop mic to do is be muffled a bit from holding a magnet on it, and the magnet won't stick by itself

Comment: I would be very surprised if that works. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Over time a magnet could damage internal components of your Mac. Speakers, for one, do not play nice with magnets.